# What is "The Center" in Justice League: The New Frontier?

Tags: plot-explanation, jl-the-new-frontier

What is "The Center" in Justice League: The New Frontier (2008)?

From where did it come to earth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[The Centre was born on primordial earth eons ago](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Centre_(Earth-21))**. It captured all life that survived the cataclysmic asteroid that wiped out nearly all life millions of years ago to protect it in what would one day become the Pacific Ocean. From there it would observe mankind's rise to become the primary dominant species of the planet, and upon their detonation of the first hydrogen bomb it sought to leave the planet, but not before wiping out all of humanity.

It's also been referred to as **[Dinosaur Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Island)**.